# Booted System Recovery Options- now what?

Tags: drivers, system-repair-disc

So after a painstaking time of extracting an .iso of the Windows 7 system recovery disk, [formating my USB to be like a CD](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-repair-windows-7-from-usb-flash-drive-repair-without-installation-dvd-disc/) and booting it, I'm stuck. I've the the System Recovery Options screen right in front of me with two options- one is restore my computer using a system image that I've created earlier, which is impossible since I haven't, and another is 'Use recovery tools that can help fix problems starting Windows. Select an operating system to repair.' But the thing is, nothings listed below on the table with the 3 columns Operating System, Partition Size and Location. So it says I have to install drivers for my hard disks.

Theres a button named 'Load Drivers'. When I click on it the pop-up window says 'Insert the installation media for the device and click OK to select the driver'. Clicking ok right now brings me to the folder explorer. I guess I need to get these drivers and put it inside my computer, justs stuck on what I need to do exactly. I'm fine hacking around with more .isos and damned USBs, cause I don't really want to spend any money (and it's fun).

The computers a HP Pavilion dv6 something (can't check) and it's dual booted Ubuntu and Windows with Grub. Kinda messed up the partitions while LiveUSBing Linux Mint so the problem occurred of my Windows installation messed up the next time I booted.

Thanks in advance, if you need me explaining anything more be sure to ask!

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly I would only use a rescue disk such as HIREN's, as all to often the Windows recovery does not meet my requirements, such as partitioning.  Could you install Windows again, and perhaps the repair option will show up?

Do your hard drives show up when you first boot?  Could be missing drivers...

Ensure your that the BIOS is configured to boot from the harddrive first.

I have not seen a requirement to load drivers in a while, what interface are you using (IDE, SATA, SCSI)?  Could be a bad option in BIOS (SATA RAID enabled, IDE mode off...).